# VBA with multiple while conditions

Tags: vba

I need some help to modify my code so as to have the correct values in column `J`.
I colored for better understanding, the rows where I have the same values from columns `A to D`
In column `J` I want to have the correct values as follows:
 - if `row 6 = row 7` then `J6 = 2`
 - if `row 8 = row 9 = row 10` then `J8 = 3`
 - and so on

My code is not good enough, because I don't want to have those `red values` in column `J`

```
Dim tw As Worksheet: Set tw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("stack")
Dim row As Integer

row = tw.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

lin = 2

Do Until lin = row + 1
nr = 1

    While (tw.Cells(lin, 1) = tw.Cells(lin + nr, 1) And tw.Cells(lin, 2) = tw.Cells(lin + nr, 2) And tw.Cells(lin, 3) = tw.Cells(lin + nr, 3) And tw.Cells(lin, 4) = tw.Cells(lin + nr, 4))

        nr = nr + 1

    Wend

    If nr = 1 Then
    Else
         tw.Cells(lin, 10) = nr
    End If

lin = lin + 1
Loop
```

[image]

Comment: I found the solution: after `tw.Cells(lin, 10) = nr` I put `lin = lin + nr - 1` to jump the rows.

Comment: Or just =COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, B2, C:C, C2, D:D, D2)

Comment: @drgs Definitely not, you didn't understand the question

Comment: What if the table is unsorted?

Comment: It is every time